# CKEditor Resize

Tags: jakarta-ee, ckeditor

Is there a way to re-size the CKEditor width dynamically based on the width of the window?

In my J2EE application, users tend to decrease or increase the width of the browser window frequently and expect the CKEditor to automatically re-size to the new width.

I guess I need to capture the window re-size event and reset the editor width. However I am not sure how this can be implemented. Any hint on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor will automatically adjust to container's width if no `config.width` is specified. See [the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/NnVUU/).

If you wish to manipulate width manually, use [editor.resize()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-resize) method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try autoGrow plugin on CKEditor ?

http://ckeditor.com/addon/autogrow